# Web Browsers Refusing to Render PHP Code

Tags: php, linux, browser, render, plaintext

I'm running on Linux Backtrack5 R3 via VMWare on Windows 7.

On my Linux OS I have Apache2, PHP5 and MySQL14 installed. When I make a simple test.php file and try opening it with Firefox 14.0.1, it tries to download the file. Not the result I was after since I already have the file :/

After searching around and finding no answers, I decided to install Opera and try opening test.php on Opera 12.14 for Linux i386. Even though it didn't ask me to download the file, it still didn't give me the result I wanted. It didn't render the PHP at all, it just displayed plain text as if I was viewing the source code in notepad.

For example, I would have the file text.php containing `<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>`.

- Upon opening the file in Firefox, it says "Do you wish to save or
  open the file test.php?"
- Upon opening the file in Opera, instead of displaying "Hello World",
  it displays "`<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>` ".

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you accessing the `.php` file?

Comment: I've just been typing file://localhost/root/Desktop/test.php into the address bar of my browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers don't execute php files, servers do. Your server is delivering the php file instead of executing it. You should be returning the file as text/html but I'd bet it's being delivered as php which no browser knows what to do with.

In your comment you say you are accessing the file directly instead of going through the server. This means the php file will never be executed by the server. You must put it in a directory on the server so it can interpret your PHP and serve it properly to browsers.